# Dynamic Destination VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make my VBA destination to the cell below the ActiveCell. Right now, it only wants to place it in R2. I have tried using offset to shift it down a cell, but haven't had any luck. The array would typically hold something like Doe, John JDoe11@email.com.

```
Sub MailMergeNames()
'
' MailMergeNames Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
    '
    ' Shift line to rows
    '

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("R1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar _
        :="<", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
        1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12 _
        , 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), _
        Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array( _
        25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), _
        Array(32, 1), Array(33, 1), Array(34, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(36, 1), Array(37, 1), Array( _
        38, 1), Array(39, 1), Array(40, 1), Array(41, 1), Array(42, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(44, 1), _
        Array(45, 1), Array(46, 1), Array(47, 1), Array(48, 1), Array(49, 1), Array(50, 1), Array( _
        51, 1), Array(52, 1), Array(53, 1), Array(54, 1), Array(55, 1), Array(56, 1), Array(57, 1), _
        Array(58, 1), Array(59, 1), Array(60, 1), Array(61, 1), Array(62, 1), Array(63, 1), Array( _
        64, 1), Array(65, 1), Array(66, 1), Array(67, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("R1:CJ1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("R2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '
    ' Trim Values
    '

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim Cell As Range
    'Also Treat CHR 0160, as a space (CHR 032)
    Selection.Replace what:=Chr(160), Replacement:=Chr(32), _
                      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    'Trim in Excel removes extra internal spaces, VBA does not
    On Error Resume Next   'in case no text cells in selection
    For Each Cell In Intersect(Selection, _
                               Selection.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues))
        Cell.Value = Application.Trim(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    '
    ' Deliminate Rows to Columns
    '

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("R2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:= _
        "<", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1)) _
        , TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


    Range("R1", "AAA1").Clear
    Range("R2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: just delete `Range("R2").Select` below `Selection.Copy` and replace `Selection.PasteSpecial` just below if with `ActiveCell.PasteSpecial`

Comment: also you may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select?rq=1 a useful read to introduce you to the next steps from macro recorder

Comment: That didn't seem to work... I got an error at the ActiveCell.PasteSpecial